# How to refer a interface that's used before it was defined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am defining TypeScript interfaces and landed in a situation where I need to define circular interface.

Eg. `ISchool have IStudent` and `IStudent have ISchool`, the problem is `interface ISchool {}` has `IStudent` which is used before it's defined. Also, I can't define `interface IStudent` before because `IStudent has ISchool`. How can handle this situation?

```
interface ISchool {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  students: IStudent[];
}

interface IStudent {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  school: ISchool;
}
```

Comment: I don't get any error, when [trying your code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUEAsD2OA2yA3gLABQyywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNzmUhwC2E9JixAcujMAFdqEcA3oZJ08AG0AupzIBfcuVCRYiFAqkywxMTUHM2G7nwHjhoio2x588zLgIbtZctII+HBQKAg4IEyu3h5oXu4a5AxuBAB0TCayygAMqukp+EA)?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I am getting eslint error, `'IStudent' was used before it was defined.eslintno-use-before-define`

Comment: That's a linter error, and not a problem on the TS side. There may be valid reasons to rather prevent such cycles, but that's an opinion, or design choice, depending on the individual circumstances.

Comment: You might want to tag this with `eslint` because your problem has less to do with TypeScript than it does with ESLint (and it has even less to do with JavaScript).  I don't know why you'd want to enable that particular lint rule for interfaces.  Does this rule get really angry at the DOM, which has all kinds of circular references?

Answer (score 0):

Better not to have circular dependencies in general. If you create a school with students the students contain a school which also contains students which also contains a school etc. That's why I reccomend you to rewrite your code so your IStudent interface references the schools with its id.

```
export interface ISchool {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    students: IStudent[];
  }
  
export interface IStudent {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    school: string;
}
```

Now you can pass the id of the school to the IStudent so your IStudent interface is still linked with your ISchool interface.

Or you could disable the eslint rule by adding this to your .eslintrc.json. Because after all its jsut a lint error and javascript allows almost everything.

```
"no-use-before-define": "off"
```

Comment: Well it just depends on how you implement it. And yes the code completion will agree with your reasoning, but the actual implementation will not. What prevents your code to not create an infinite loop in objects when the interface is used? Right nothing. It's a way to prevent bugs. I've updated my answer